# How to properly swap two values in array using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

What could be the best way to swap two values in a tensor given two indexes ?

Here is what I've done so far using a Variable.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

indices = tf.constant([0,1])
data = tf.Variable([1,2,8])
data = tf.scatter_update(data,indices,tf.gather(data,tf.reverse(indices,[0])))
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([init_op])
print "data:", sess.run(data)
```

It is giving me

> a: [2 1 8]

I'm sure this is ugly, is there another way to do it ?

Regards,